# custom typeahead implemented, additional feature required

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typeahead

I have created a custom typeahead in Angular. Checkout the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9myakc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I have to add two more features here, but I can't figure out how to implement.

1. When user starts typing and options are shown, then matching characters from the displayed options should be of different color, let's say blue or red
2. Right now am able to select the options from displayed menu by clicking on it by mouse, I want to add option for navigation and selection from keyboard also.

Kindly advise how can I proceed to implement these above mentioned features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first feature you can do something like below:

Create a highlight.pipe.ts file with the following code:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'highlight' }) export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {   transform(text: string, search): string {
    if (search && text) {
      let pattern = search.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
      pattern = pattern.split(' ').filter((t) => {
        return t.length > 0;
      }).join('|');
      const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');

      return text.replace(regex, (match) => `<span class="search-highlight">${match}</span>`);
    } else {
      return text;
    }   } }
```

Inject this pipe in app.module.ts

```
import { HighlightPipe } from './highlight.pipe';
```

Update your app component

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <h5>Sample Custom Typeahead</h5>
        <p>Try typing "Win" or "Mob" in input box below</p>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchByThis" (keyup)="showDropdown()">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div (clickOutside)="closeDropDown()">
            <div class='search-drop-down' *ngIf="displayDropdown">

                <div (click)='selectValue(product)' class='search-results' *ngFor="let product of sampleItemDetails | searchFilter: searchByThis ">

                    <div [innerHTML]="product.name  | highlight : searchByThis">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to update your CSS : app.component.css

```
:host ::ng-deep .search-highlight{
  background-color: #F2E366;
}
```

I have referred this [gist](https://gist.github.com/adamrecsko/0f28f474eca63e0279455476cc11eca7#gistcomment-2103489)

Comment: wow!! thank @Syed Arshad, this solution worked. Please post for the second feature also.

Comment: Oh cool, sorry for the late reply. Quite busy working. Will check for the next one in sometime.